# Get Facebook's Hosting API for App Links

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the app_link_hosts using facebook graph version method for IOS,but am getting error message.Can any one help me to fix this issue.
Facebook and App Link's documentation is not clear.

Here is the code,

```
 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"app name", @"name",
                        theUrl, @"al:ios:url",
                        @"app store id", @"al:ios_id",
                        @"app name", @"al:ios:app_name",
                        @"{\"should_fallback\": false}", @"web",
                        fbAccessToken, @"access_token",
                        nil
                        ];

/* make the API call */

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/(fb app id)/app_link_hosts"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
                          if(error) NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
                      }];
```

This is the error i got,

```
 error = Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x8c7d4b0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=403, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) Permissions error";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 403;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x9a53750, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x9a51fd0, appID: 443803585653119, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x9a52960>, expirationDate: 2014-09-12 10:12:17 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-07-14 12:00:51 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
installed,
"public_profile",
"publish_actions",
"user_friends"
)>}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are using the "user access token" instead of the "app token" that is required for generating app links. try to generate a test link using the Graph api explorer - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ (selecting the app token option), as it is not good practice to generate from client devices.